# Capture TAB key in test suite of Selenium IDE

Tags: tabs, selenium-ide

I have tried with the following in Selenium IDE to press TAB button,

**

```
Command: keyPress
Target: id=topMenu:j_idt17:5:j_idt19
Value: \9
```

**

Its not working, Pls help me.

Browser: FireFox 22.0
OS: windows

Answer (score 5):

You can use ${KEY_TAB} to special key. Like below.

```
Command: keyPress
Target: id=topMenu:j_idt17:5:j_idt19
Value: ${KEY_TAB}
```

You can get more information about special keys in below links.

http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-1/
http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2/

Hope it will help you.
:)

Comment: more than a year old answer, and thanks :) i find selenium website such a mess that it's easier to find real answer in the real interwebs.